# Examining measurability of a function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and let $f:[0,1] \to \bar {\Bbb R}$ be defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x-2, & \text{if x $\in$ A} \\
x+2, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

How should I examine the measurability of $f$?

I have definition of measurability of a function as follows:

> Let $f:X \to \Bbb R$. we say $f$ is $\mathscr A$-measurable if:
>
> 1. $f^{-1}(+\infty) \in \mathscr A$, $f^{-1}(-\infty) \in \mathscr A$; and
> 2. $f^{-1}(U) \in \mathscr A$ for every open $U \subset \Bbb R$

I have no clue as to where should I begin. If I choose some open $U \subset \Bbb R$ then how will I get it's inverse image under $f$ inside the $\sigma$-algebra?Am I working on a Lebesgue measure?

Comment: can you find the inverse image of open set $(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: Do you know that the sum of two measurable functions is measurable?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes I know that.

Comment: @drhab Got you! :) Also if we choose $U=(2,\infty)$, then $f$ will be measurable on $[0,1] \setminus A$ since $f^{-1}(U)=[0,1] \setminus A$. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Well then, $f_1(x) = x+2$ is continuous and therefore measurable, and the indicator function of $A$ is $(f_1(x) - f(x))/4$.  So if $f$ were measurable, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us take a look at possible values of $f(x)$ when $x\notin   A$: $$0\le x\le 1\Rightarrow 2\le f(x)\le 3.$$

If $x\in   A $, then $-2\le f(x)\le -1$.

Therefore, we can consider an open set $U=(-4,0)$, which gives $f^{-1}(U)=A$, which is not measurable.

Comment: @drhab indeed, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating more clearly! :) Can we conclude that f is non-measurable on $A$ and measurable on $[0,1] \setminus A$ for more clarity in the proof?

Comment: @VikrantDesai The conclusion is not: "$f$ is not measurable on $A$". The conclusion is: "$f$ is not measurable". This because the condition  "$f^{-1}(U)\in\mathscr A$ for each open $U\subset\mathbb R$" is not satisfied. This answer shows that $f^{-1}((-4,0))\notin\mathscr A$. Questions like "Is $f$ measurable on $[0,1]\setminus A$?" do not belong in this context. You are only investigating the measurability of $f$. Not its measurability on some set.

Comment: @drhab Thank you so much. This helped me a lot!

Comment: @VikrantDesai Glad to help.